# ConfigurationErrorException in trying to run console app with MySQL Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to learn how to use Entity Framework 6 with MySQL. Since I already have an existing database, I am following the Model First approach. However, I am always faced with this error message that is vaguely helpful.

The error triggers in this line of code in Program.cs:

```
List<Student> students = dbContext.Students.ToList();
```

The error message just says:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' occurred in System.Configuration.dll Additional information: Unrecognized attribute 'name'.

My first assumption is that there is something wrong with my App.config file. However, I don't know which `name` attribute in the App.config file it was talking about. I tried searching for existing answers or possible solutions to no avail so I decided to post my problem hoping for you guys to help me.

---

What I am using:

- Visual Studio 2013 (Installed in my PC)
- MySQL Server 5.6 (Installed in my PC)
- Entity Framework 6.1.1 (Installed in my project through NuGet Package Manager)
- MySql.ConnectorNET.Data 6.8.3.2 (Installed in my project through NuGet Package Manager)
- MySql.ConnectorNet.Entity 6.8.3.2 (Installed in my project through NuGet Package Manager)

---

What steps I did:

1. Created a new console app
2. Installed Entity Framework, MySql.ConnectorNET.Data, and MySql.ConnectorNet.Entity into the project through NuGet Package Manager
3. Added an ADO.Net Entity Data Model named `DSWS_Model` using my existing database
4. Entered some simple code that iterates and prints the list of students into the console
5. RUN
6. Then stupid runtime error shows up

---

Program.cs

```
namespace MySQLEntityFramework6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start?");
            Console.ReadLine();
            try
            {
                using (dswsEntities dbContext = new dswsEntities())
                {
                    List<Student> students = dbContext.Students.ToList();
                    foreach (Student student in students)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(student.name);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ExceptionUtility.LogException(ex);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

---

DSWS_Model.Context.cs

```
namespace MySQLEntityFramework6
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class dswsEntities : DbContext
    {
        public dswsEntities()
            : base("name=dswsEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Administrator> Administrators { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<BuildingSetting> BuildingSettings { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Evaluation> Evaluations { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<LockerReservation> LockerReservations { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Locker> Lockers { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<LoginQueue> LoginQueues { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="dswsEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DSWS_Model.csdl|res://*/DSWS_Model.ssdl|res://*/DSWS_Model.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=localhost;user id=root;password=root;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=dsws&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

---

Error Log

```
    Exception Type: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
Exception: Unrecognized attribute 'name'. (C:\Users\Nico\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\MVA\Entity Framework\MySQLEntityFramework6\MySQLEntityFramework6\bin\Debug\MySQLEntityFramework6.vshost.exe.Config line 23)
Source: System.Configuration
Stack Trace: 
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.EvaluateOne(String[] keys, SectionInput input, Boolean isTrusted, FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.Evaluate(FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult, Boolean getLkg, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String configKey)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at System.Configuration.PrivilegedConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String providerInvariantName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DefaultProviderFactoryResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key, Func`3 handleFailedLookup)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DefaultProviderFactoryResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.CachingDependencyResolver.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetService>b__0(Tuple`2 k)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.CachingDependencyResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.<>c__DisplayClass3.<GetService>b__0(IDbDependencyResolver r)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.GetService(Type type, Object key)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.RootDependencyResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.<>c__DisplayClass3.<GetService>b__0(IDbDependencyResolver r)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.GetService(Type type, Object key)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.CompositeResolver`2.GetService(Type type, Object key)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DbDependencyResolverExtensions.GetService[T](IDbDependencyResolver resolver, Object key)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.ChangeConnectionString(String newConnectionString)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.InitializeFromConnectionStringSetting(ConnectionStringSettings appConfigConnection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.TryInitializeFromAppConfig(String name, AppConfig config)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.CreateObjectContextFromConnectionModel()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at MySQLEntityFramework6.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\Nico\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\MVA\Entity Framework\MySQLEntityFramework6\MySQLEntityFramework6\Program.cs:line 19
Target Site: System.Object EvaluateOne(System.String[], System.Configuration.SectionInput, Boolean, System.Configuration.FactoryRecord, System.Configuration.SectionRecord, System.Object)
```

---

Thank you in advance for those who will reply.

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace of the exception? That should help to get to the root cause of the configuration issue.

Comment: Posted the full stack trace in the error log. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your stack trace it would appear that it's complaining about the 'name' attribute on one of the DbProviderFactory elements in your configuration file. You don't need to specify name on the remove element, just invariant. Try removing it and things should start working!

Comment: Thank you so much! :)
BTW, it's funny how it never occurred to me to check the stack trace. Pretty much gave exactly which line in the config file that has the problem. I blame my Error Message searching habits. :P

Comment: Thank you, @Dean. I realized it was an app.config issue, but not that the remove element didn't need the name element. Without this answer, I could have been searching for a long time.